# Change button color in rich text editor

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a simple rich text editor using *javascript*, it currently has one button i.e **Bold button** (just for simplicity).

But I want the color of the button to change to blue, to show that the bold button is active and hence all text on wards would be bold.

And when i'm done with bolding . I would again click on the bold button, and it's color should change to silver, to show bold is not active any more. I have written following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Rich text editor</title>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/bac4a9a15f.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="enableEditMode()">

    <button onclick="hlite()" id="bold" style="color:silver;display:block;"><i class="fa fa-bold"></i></button>

<iframe name="richTextField" src="" frameborder="0" style="width:1000px; height:500px; border:1px solid black;"></iframe>
<script>
    function enableEditMode(){
        richTextField.document.designMode = 'on';
    }

    function execCmd(command) {
        richTextField.document.execCommand(command, false,null);
    }

    function hlite(){

        color = document.getElementById('bold').style.color;
       if(color == 'silver'){
           console.log(color);
        document.getElementById('bold').style.color = "blue";
        execCmd('bold');
        color = 'blue';
       }else {

        document.getElementById('bold').style.color = "silver";
        }

    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The button changes from silver to blue and from blue to silver for me. I'm using Chrome.

Comment: It does change, when it changes from silver to blue the text on wards is bold now when i again click the bold button the color of button changes from blue to silver but text on wards is still bold. To get rid of bold i have to again click the button which is my third click and color of button changes to blue and now at third click i get rid of bold. And remember at third click button is blue and when button is blue it is supposed to make text bold and not normal text.